# How to jump X bytes down in hexedit?

Tags: memory, hexdump

I am looking through a memory dump

```
B79C6440   64 6F 6E 65  00 00 6C 5F  75 62 6C 65  20 73 68 6F  done..l_uble sho
B79C6450   77 5F 00 00  5F 6F 6E 5F  72 75 70 00  00 61 63 6B  w_.._on_rup..ack
B79C6460   69 72 71 5F  76 65 63 74  6F 72 73 10  10 05 30 10  irq_vectors...0.
B79C6470   06 50 10 07  70 10 08 90  10 09 B0 10  0A 98 1B FC  .P..p...........
B79C6480   16 9C 1B A0  A4 A8 18 6E  6D 69 5F 63  68 65 63 6B  .......nmi_check
```

using Hexedit I can jump to a new address by pressing enter and typing the address in.

Say I want to move from address `B79C6440` by adding an offset of X bytes , how could I compute the new address I want to reach so I could type it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, aside from using e.g. `bc` or your  shell (simply `echo "$((0xB79C6440 + 1234))`), you can't.

Let's be honest here, `hexedit` is a fine tool with a time-honored tradition, but it's hardly the hexeditor of choice if you're really trying to move around complex files:

- if you're looking at executable program code / libraries, `radare2` is a very potent tool that also allows you to directly follow jumps, can analyze the binary to extract functions, analyze the entropy in regions of the file to find specific content etc
- if you're looking to analyze a data storage file format, Ange Albertini's [sbud](https://github.com/corkami/sbud) is probably more what you're looking for. [There's a neat presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=264OmDG8m7M) about that problem.
- if you're used to using emacs, anyway, guess what major mode exists
- vim has a pretty popular hex-editor mode: in fact, one of the most commonly used tools to just dump the content of a file as hex (as opposed to interactively jump around in it) has its name from it, `xxd`. You enter the hex-edit mode by typing `:%xxd` in vim.

Looking at your dump, this looks like something that is going to get loaded as process image or directly as bare-metal firmware: radare2's `r2` is the tool to use, really.

Comment: Thanks, I really just need to dump a handful, fixed length section out of this, but this is quite out of my expertise, your first line looks like what I needed. Thanks for the software suggestion too

Comment: if you just need to *dump* things, not interactively move around, then `xxd` is probably a better tool; you can use `xxd -o "$((0xB79C6440 + 1234)) -l 256"` to output 256 bytes starting at the calculated offset, (decimal) 1234 bytes after (hexadecimal) B79C6440.

Comment: That's NEAT, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If you need to process these dumps further on to HTML, PNG, SVG etc, really, have a look at [sbud](https://github.com/corkami/sbud)'s dis->dat chain. might save you a lot of effort.